# Редирект, если файла нет

Tags: .htaccess, php

Хочу потихонечку перевести свой сайт на ЧПУ. Поэтому вопрос: как делать редирект на файл index.php, если запрос пришел на файл, которого нет. Т.е. хочу чтобы старые .php файлы продолжали работать, но при запросе какого-нибудь нового адреса, если по нему ничего не лежит, обрабатывать его в index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteMode on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#не файл
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#не директория
RewriteRule (.*)/? index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- `(.*)` - все подряд
- `/?` - со слэшом и без (необязательно. Но яперестраховываюсь)
- `$1` - то, что схавали первые скобки
- `L` - последнее правило. После него ничего выполняться дальше не будет
- `QSA` - добавить к файлу строку запроса. `QueryStringAdd`.

Comment: Как это применить?
Для меня это не очевидно ):

Comment: Ну, я ожидал, что раз разговор об HTACCESS, вы знаете что с этим делать.
Открываете файл .htaccess, там пишете.
См обновленную версию.